# XCode 6.4 submission

Tags: xcode6, ios9, xcode7

As new Xcode 7 released, Swift 2.0 also arrived. I've got a big project build in 1.2 and migrating to 2.0 standard can take a long time. Did anyone submit apps from 6.* Xcode? Or i MUST update my app and build it with 7.0 release? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i must update, i've updated and it was really painful